# Winforms Panel resize causing scroll to top in parent

Tags: c#, winforms

Using WinForms, C#...

I have a UserControl that contains a few panels.
When I programatically resize the panel, it causes the scroll bar to scroll to the top. I would like to prevent this as it is frustrating for the user to have the control scroll to the top.

I've tried to use "ScrollToControl()" after the resize bu this isnt practical as you still see the form jump and the once focused control is now at the bottom of the control.

Have tried to access the AutoScrollPosition but it returns 0. this.VerticalScroll.Value also returns 0 (where this is the user control before the resize event)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which panel is resized? Or is it the uc? Which has the scrollbar? The one you resize? Does the Uc have anything to do with it? Can you post an image or two?

Comment: The user control contains a panel. The panel is resized. The scroll bar belonging to the user control or the user controls parent (can't tell) is scrolled to the top when the panel is programmatically resized.

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce. Did the scrollbars get show via uc.AutoScroll?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'll create a sample project. I thought the issue was clearly described

Comment: _The scroll bar belonging to the user control or the user controls parent (can't tell)_ Well, it doesn't seem to be quite clear to yourself..